# Why parentheses (grouping operator) aren't needed to call a "get method" through an instance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am reading about JavaScript Classes at [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), and see an example where a method is defined using a `get` keyword. Here, I noticed that no parentheses (grouping operator `()`) are required to call such a method (defined using `get` keyword) through an instance of the class.

Like, in following example,

- `square.area` syntax calls the `Rectangle` Class's `area` method.
- However, `square.area()` throws an error **`Uncaught TypeError: square.area is not a function`**.

Can someone please explain what am I missing here?

**Here is the example:**

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square.area); // 100
console.log(square.area()); // Uncaught TypeError: square.area is not a function
```

Comment: `area` isn't a method, it's a property. You only defined a getter for said property

Comment: A getter acts as a property, so it doesn't need to be called as a function.

Comment: In the context of a function call, `()` isn't a grouping operator…

Comment: @deceze can you explain in what specific scenarios we **can and cannot** call `()` a **grouping operator**?

Comment: @aaditya if it does not follow an identifier its a grouping operator.

Comment: When you use it to *call a function*, it's not a *grouping* operator. If you use it to *group expressions* `(a + b) * c`, then it's a *grouping* operator.

Comment: You can read about [getters on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Answer (score 1):

The *grouping operator* is used to change the evaluation order in calculations, e.g.

```
  (a + b) * c
```

parens that follow an identifier however like in your case aren't a *grouping operator*, they are a *function call*. You can only call functions and constructors though, not getters, which act like regular properties to the outside.