# Parentheses "()" vs Grouping Operator? Do they always represent the same thing?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, does the term **Grouping Operator** always represent the **parentheses `()`** and vice versa?

Or are there any scenarios where the above statement doesn't hold true? In other words:

> - In what specific scenarios we **can and cannot** call `()` a *grouping operator*?

---

PS:: I asked this question here after seeing [this comment on a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552992/why-parentheses-grouping-operator-arent-needed-to-call-a-get-method-through?noredirect=1#comment101568491_57552992).

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The grouping operator is used to group expressions together, especially in mathematical use. What do you mean by **represents the parenthesis**?

Comment: @Kobe For clarity, I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Im still not sure I understand your question, nor the problem. You can use the grouping operator almost anywhere in javascript.

Comment: well, I wouldn't call the parentheses used in an if-statement (`if(condition)` ) using the grouping operator, same with calling functions (`x(foo)`), so in these cases, I wouldn't call the use of parenthesis a grouping operator

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses are often used in JavaScripts grammar with different meaning:

1. As function invokation

```
someFunction(a,b)
```

2. As argument definition (inside arrow, async, generator, or plain function declarations, function expressions, method shorthands)

```
function someFunction(x,y){}
```

3. As part of statements, e.g. `if`, `catch`, `for` or `while`

```
if(condition){}

try{}
catch(exception){}

for(let i=0;i<n;i++){}
```

Answer (score 1):

> does the term Grouping Operator always represent the parentheses ()

Yes. The operator is used in expressions when you need to change the precedence of operators. For example, run addition before multiplication. More details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping

And the complete table of precedence:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

> and vice versa

No. Parentheses are also used as part of functions. You need to use them to define parameters and call the functions. Like:

```
myFunction(a){
   return a;
}

myFunction("Hello!");
```

Or they used to specify conditions in if, for, while statements:

```
if(a === true){...}
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){...}
```